# Спроба класифікувати теги / A try to classify tags

Tags: discussion, info, obsolete

В цьому питанні є вікі-відповідь зі спробою класифікувати наявні теги.

---

This question has a wiki-answer trying to classify existing tags.

Answer (score 3):

<sub>Попередня версія цієї відповіді (нині видалена) намагалася *запропонувати* «правильні» теги. Ця відповідь не пропонує нові теги, а лише намагається систематизувати *ті, що є*. Але знак «=», як правило, позначає *плановані* синоніми, а не ті, що вже пов'язані між собою.</sub>

<sub>Previous version of this answer (now deleted) tried to *propose* “right” tags. This answer doesn't propose new tags, just tries to systematize those that *already exist*. But the “=” sign mostly denotes *planned* synonyms, not the already linked ones.</sub>

### By language aspect

A language consists of:

1. Medium-independent stuff:

   - Words & meanings (lexicon, semantics, phraseology):

     [connotation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connotation) [idioms](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idioms) [russianism](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russianism) [terminology](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology)=[терміни](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%96%d0%bd%d0%b8) [word-difference](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-difference) [word-interchangeability](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-interchangeability) [word-meaning](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-meaning)=[значення-слів](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%96%d0%b2) [word-usage](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage)=[використання-слів](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%96%d0%b2) [loan-words](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loan-words) [neologisms](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neologisms) [polonism](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polonism) [slang](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slang)
   - Neologism creation (word formation <sub>a part of grammar</sub>):

     [grammar](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) [loan-words](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loan-words) [neologisms](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neologisms) [transliteration](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transliteration)
   - Word-forms (morphology <sub>a part of grammar</sub>):

     [cases](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cases) [conjugation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjugation) [grammar](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) [noun-cases](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noun-cases) [past-tense](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/past-tense) [vocative](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocative)
   - Using words together (syntax <sub>a part of grammar</sub>):

     [grammar](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar)
2. Speaking-related stuff:

   - Sounds & pronunciations (phonetics, phonology):

     [consonants](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/consonants) [phonetics](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phonetics) [phonology](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phonology) [pronunciation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation)=[вимова](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)
   - Stress-position:

     [stress](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stress)=[наголос](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81)
3. Writing-related stuff:

   - Letters/signs/etc & shapes (graphetics?):

     [alphabet](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alphabet)=[абетка](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0) [latin-script](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latin-script) [there's no such tag but I feel [this question](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/40/4) would fit here too]
   - Making a single word (орфографія, spelling, hyphenation, capitalization, word breaks):

     [capitalization](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/capitalization)=[велика-літера](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d1%96%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0) [orthography](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography) [spelling](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling) [орфографія](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%80%d1%84%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d1%96%d1%8f) [правопис](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81)
   - Signs between words (пунктуація, inter-word punctuation):

     [punctuation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation)
4. Other:

   - Historical:

     [etymology](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology)=[етимологія](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%96%d1%8f) [language-history](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-history)=[history](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) [ономастика](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0)
   - Learning:

     [learning](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning)=[вивчення-мови](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8)=[навчання](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8f) [resource-request](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-request)
   - Social:

     [connotation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connotation) [culture](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture) [etiquette](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etiquette) [language-regulation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-regulation) [sociolinguistics](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sociolinguistics) [state-institutions](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/state-institutions)
   - Technical:

     [software](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software) [text-processing](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing)
   - About foreign languages:

     [cross-language-comparison](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-language-comparison) [loan-words](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loan-words) [polonism](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polonism) [russianism](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russianism) [translation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation)=[переклад](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4)=[correspondence](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/correspondence) [transliteration](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transliteration)

### The refining tags

Some of these tags are really non-informative without other tags (e.g. [nouns](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nouns) can be: [translation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) [nouns](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nouns), [grammar](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) [nouns](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nouns) or [word-difference](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-difference) [nouns](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nouns)) — still they're popular:

- By parts of speech:

  [adjective](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adjective)=[прикметники](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8) [conjunctions](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conjunctions)=[сполучники](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8) [nouns](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nouns) ([proper-names](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proper-names) ) [numeral](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numeral)=[числівники](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%96%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8) [pronouns](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronouns) [verbs](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbs)
- By grammatical cases:

  [vocative](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocative)
- By letters:

  [soft-sign](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-sign)
- By words:

  [бути](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8)

### Technical

- Describing author's identity:

  [non-native-speaker](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-native-speaker)
- Question types:

  [resource-request](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-request)

### Unclassified

[expression](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expression)=[вираз](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7) [folk](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folk) [linguistics](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linguistics) [mnemonic](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mnemonic) [speaking](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speaking) [swearing](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swearing) [transcription](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transcription) [методологія](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%96%d1%8f) [одним-словом](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc) [питомі-слова](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%96-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0) [проект-99](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-99) [усталені-слова](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%96-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53657/discussion-between-bytebuster-and-sasha).

Comment: На мою думку синоніми spelling, orthography та орфографія

Comment: @Artemix, як не дивно — ні. [Orthography](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthography) — це загальні правила правопису, в тому числі пунктуація. [Орфограція](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Орфографія) (принаймні в шкільному розумінні) включає в себе правила написання слів, переносу, капіталізації та разом-чи-окремо — але не пунктуацію. [Spelling](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelling) включає в себе саме написання слів, але не перенос чи капіталізацію та, тим більше, не пунктуацію. Orthography > орфограції > spelling. Але ми *можемо* зробити їх синонімами *у нас* — просто бо більшість вживає у вузьких значеннях.