# How do we make tag synonyms for orthography, spelling, and related?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Прошу допомоги у створенні синонімів до групи теґів, пов'язаних з орфографією.

З точки зору українського мовознавства, структура така:

- [правопис](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81), і його частини:

  - [орфографія](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%80%d1%84%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d1%96%d1%8f)
  - [пунктуація](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d1%96%d1%8f)

Причому, *орфографія* і *правопис* часто використовуються як синоніми.

З точки зору англійського мовознавства, усе виглядає інакше:

- [orthography](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography), і його частини:

  - [spelling](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling)
  - [capitalization](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/capitalization)
  - тощо

Прошу допомоги, щоб гарно оформити, враховуючи, що у нас первинними вважаються україномовні теґи.

Answer (score 1):

Дякую що винесли це в окреме питання, у нас вже було обговорення тегів, але у великому пості важко було побачити що не так з цими тегами.

Думаю що тут ми маємо ту ж проблему що із тегом [лінгвістика](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d1%96%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%b2%d1%96%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0) - у нас 99% відсотків питань стосуються лінгвістики. Так само [правопис](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81) - думаю що близько 50% питань будуть мати цей тег, а отже використання такого тегу не має сенсу.

Мені здається що треба зберегти окремість орфографії та пунктуації, оскільки це окремі теми і людина що знається на пунктуації (наприклад професійний редактор) може бути зацікавлена у відстеженні питань саме по пунктуації, а орфографія може бути не настільки цікавою.

І навпаки: людина, що знається саме на орфографії може бути не зацікавленою у відстеженні питаннь щодо пунктуації.

Тож я вважаю що треба поєднати [орфографія](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%80%d1%84%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d1%96%d1%8f)=[spelling](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling), [велика-літера](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d1%96%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0)=[capitalization](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/capitalization), [пунктуація](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d1%96%d1%8f)=[punctuation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation). А [правопис](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81) рекомендувати для загальних питаннь (зміни у правописі у різних роках, проекти і їх обгворення і таке інше).

Щодо [orthography](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography) - я, наприклад, не знав що це не "орфографія", тож все-таки добре що ми взяли українські теги за головні і, можливо, цей "фальшивий друг перекладача" не буде з'являтися у неправильному значенні.

Comment: О, це ви слушно зауважили щодо загальних/детальних аспектів. Справа в тім, що якщо робити ієрархію, то треба, як мінімум, розписати це у tag wiki, бо люди плутатимуться. Я і сам плутаюся, я свої запитання переглянув, там також жах :)

Comment: А «лінгвістику» (і ще кілька подібних) ми видалимо, бо є цілий SE сайт для того.

Comment: @bytebuster У нас було декілька теоретичних питань, які можна віднести до лінгвістики - щось типу автоматичного аналізу текстів, якісь частотні дослідження і таке інше. Можливо такі теоретичні питання, для яких не варто створювати спеціалізовані теги можна було б відносити до "лінгвістики взагалі щодо української мови".

Comment: Цілком згоден. Пропоную «допилити» першу чергу синонімів, тоді список теґів значно скоротиться, і в ньому можна буде орієнтуватися і допрацьовувати те, що лишилося поза увагою зараз.

Answer (score 1):

Просто для інформації (хоч я вже писав про це [тут](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/51#comment256_86), [тут](//meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/85/4) і ще в деяких місцях): вони **формально** не синоніми.

Orthography > правопис > орфографія > spelling, бо:

- [orthography](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthography) = spelling + hyphenation + capitalization + word breaks + emphasis + punctuation;
- [правопис](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81) = орфографія + пунктуація;
- [орфографія](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D1%8F) = spelling + word breaks + capitalization + puntuation.

Punctuation > пунктуація, бо:

- [пунктуація](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F) вивчає постановку лише власне [розділових знаків](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8), до яких не відносяться так звані [нелітерні орфографічні знаки](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA) (апостроф, дефіс, в т.ч. в ролі знаку переносу, знак наголосу, й, можливо, навіть точка в скороченнях, але щодо останнього не впевнений), тобто: ком, тире, крапок, знаків питання тощо;
- [punctuation](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation) же включає в себе будь-які нелітерні знаки: як (з точки зору українського мовознавста) розділові, так і (з точки зору українського мовознавста) орфографічні.

Але я не впевнений, що нам треба робити систему теґів, у якій сам чорт ногу зломить. Можливо, при створенні синонімів ми повинні керуватися **не тим, що воно формально означає, а тим, які асоціації викликає в користувачів**. Тоді нам більше заважатиме «зробити синонімами orthography, правопис, орфографію і spelling» не те, що вони неоднакові, а те що, користувачі часто ставлять теґ правопис, питаючи про саму правописну систему (наприклад: скрипніківка, проект-99 тощо).

Comment: Перегляньте, будь ласка, фразу «Тоді нам більше заважатиме…»: мені здається, там по смислу щось не сходиться. З допису випливає, що ви радите саме зробити ці теґи синонімами?

Comment: @bytebuster, як один з варіантів — так. Бо так їх розуміє широкий загал, а не 1% «обраних». Можу написати докладніше про цей варіант у окремій відповіді (як саме я пропоную це зробити, щоби і 1% «обраних» не образити, і за 99% іншими не виправляти). Спеціально не писав про це тут, бо хотів відділити «факти» від «дуже дискусійної пропозиції» (одного з варіантів).

Answer (score 1):

Врешті, я пропоную зробити так.

#### Орфографія, написання, orthography, spelling, правопис

[орфографія](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%80%d1%84%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d1%96%d1%8f) (або, можливо, взагалі **написання** (створити такий тег)).

До «орфографія» синонім [orthography](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography). Так, orthography — не те саме, що орфографія, це гіперонім, що включає і пунктуацію. Але як багато користувачів (навіть English native speakers) про це знають? З них — який відсоток буде в питанні «де поставити кому» використовувати загальне «orthography» замість конкретного «punctuation» чи ще конкретнішого «comma»? А навіть якщо такі й будуть, то це просто вирішити, зробивши спеціальний тег «orthography-punctuation», синонімічний до «пунктуація», щоби людина, яка раптом спробує в питання «де поставити кому» засунути тег «orthography», набираючи «orthogra…», побачила підказку «orthography-punctuation»→«пунктуація» і подумала: «О, це навіть краще, ніж те, що я збирався застосувати.» Ну і плюс у тега «орфографія» зробити опис, мовляв, не використовуйте для пунктуації (для неї: «пунктуація»).

До «орфографія» також синонім [spelling](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling). Так, spelling — не те саме, що орфографія, це гіпонім. Але менше з тим.

До «орфографія» також синонім [правопис](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81). Так, правопис — не те саме, що орфографія, це гіперонім, але див. про orthography. Значно більшу проблему у випадку «правопис» становить не те, що формально це гіперонім до «орфографія», а те, що користувачі застосовують його також у випадку питань про правописи в цілому (про проект-99, про скрипніківку, про те, хто затверджує провопис тощо) — але про це див. наступну главу.

#### Правописні системи, правописи

Створити тег **правописні-системи** (або, можливо, **правописи**).

Це для того, щоб його люди могли засовувати в питання про правописи в цілому (про проект-99, про скрипніківку, про те, хто затверджує провопис тощо). Наскільки я пам'ятаю, раніше люди пхали в такі питання тег «правопис» (зараз, правда, не бачу — мабуть, або погано дивився, або хтось поприбирав).

Перевага такої назви («правописні-системи» або «правописи») в тому, що воно починається на «правопис…». Тобто, намагаючись запхнути тег «правопис» у питання про правописи в цілому, користувач, набираючи назву тегу, побачить не лише підказку «правопис»→«орфографія», а й «правописні-системи» (чи «правописи») і подумає: «О, то це краще.»

#### Розділові знаки, пунктуація, punctuation

Створити тег «розділові-знаки».

До «розділові-знаки» *можна* зробити синонімом «знаки-пунтуації» — якщо раптом такий тег хтось створить.

До «розділові-знаки» синонім [пунктуація](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d1%96%d1%8f).

До «розділові-знаки» синонім [punctuation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation). Так, punctuation — не теж саме, що пунктуація і розділові знаки, це гіпером (англійське punctuation включає також і апостроф/дефіс/наголос, що в Україні, наскільки я знаю, не вважається частиною пунктуації (а вважаються частиною орфографії)). Але вирішується просто:

- створити теги «punctuation-…», що посилається на відповідні інші теги:

  - «punctuation-hyphen» → [разом-дефіс-окремо](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d1%96%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be),
  - «punctuation-apostrophe» → «апостроф-та-мʼякий-знак»;
- в описі тегу «розділові-знаки» зазначити, що краще використовувати [разом-дефіс-окремо](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d1%96%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be) чи «апостроф-та-мʼякий-знак» замість «розділові-знаки», якщо питання стосується них.

#### Висновки

Три теги з купою синонімів:

- [орфографія](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%80%d1%84%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d1%96%d1%8f) = **написання** = [orthography](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography) = [spelling](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling) = [правопис](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81)
- **правописні-системи** = **orthographies** = **правописи** (можливо, вистачить першого)
- **розділові-знаки** = [пунктуація](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d1%96%d1%8f) = [punctuation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation) (можливо, = **orthography-punctuation** — просто щоб перенаправляти людей, що набирають «orthogra…» на **розділові-знаки**)

<sub>А, ну, ще вужчі теми:</sub>

- <sub>[велика-чи-мала-літера](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d1%96%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0) = [capitalization](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/capitalization) (можливо, = **орфографія-велика-чи-мала** = **правопис-велика-чи-мала** — просто щоби перенаправляти сюди людей з більш широких тем — необов'язково)</sub>
- <sub>[разом-дефіс-окремо](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d1%96%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be) (можливо, = **punctuation-hyphen** і т.д. — просто, щоби перенаправляти сюди людей з більш широких тем)</sub>
- <sub>**апостроф-чи-мʼякий-знак**</sub>

#### Додатковий нюанс

Чи входять теги [велика-чи-мала-літера](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d1%96%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0), [разом-дефіс-окремо](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d1%96%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be) і «**апостроф-чи-мʼякий-знак**» у тег [орфографія](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%80%d1%84%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d1%96%d1%8f)? Звісно, SE не підтримує підтегів, але мається на увазі: питаючи, наприклад, про те, чи з великої літери слід писати «інтернет», користувачу варто ставити теги [велика-чи-мала-літера](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d1%96%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0) і [орфографія](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%80%d1%84%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d1%96%d1%8f) (обидва) — чи лише тег [велика-чи-мала-літера](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d1%96%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0)?

Нагадую, що формально [велика-чи-мала-літера](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d1%96%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0) та [разом-дефіс-окремо](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d1%96%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be) входять в українське поняття орфографії, але не входять в англійське поняття spelling (але ж ми «орфографія» і «spelling» робимо синонімами).

Власне, я думаю — в першу чергу, як саме піде (ми не можемо дуже це вже контролювати). Але, якби моя воля, я б робив… а, власне, не важливо. В мене є думка, але тут уже більше як саме піде, ніж як вирішимо.

#### Питання? Критика? Альтернативи?

Comment: Мені усе подобається, усе збігається з моїм власним розумінням. По першому пункту уточнення — чи не варто зробити «правопис» головним?

Comment: По усьому іншому, пропоную тут і надалі прийняти так: це запитання обговорює одну проблему, воно не включає проблему «пунктуації» або «великої-малої-літери», і тому не варто, НМД, цим збільшувати вашу відповідь. Саме таким чином ми зможемо «їсти слона частинами» — розбивати проблему на маленькі і вирішувати їх по одній. А великі дописи «про все на світі» особисто мене пригнічують… :) Ніхто не заважає виділити шматки у окремі запитання + self-answer.

Comment: @bytebuster, я думаю, **ні**. Причини дві: (1) Правопис все таки формально ширше поняття, ніж те, до чого ми застосовуємо ту групу синонімічних тегів (орфографія = написання = правопис = orthography = spelling = …). Тобто, робити синоніморедирект з гіпероніма на гіпонім (бо в більшості такі асоціації) — це півбіди; але робити саме гіперонім (не в своєму правильному значенні) головним тегом — це гірше. (2) «Правопис», як я вже казав, намагались застосовувати до питань іншої категорії. Роблячи редирект з «правопис» на «орфографія» чи «написання» (а не навпаки) ми, мені здається, зменшуємо це.

Comment: @bytebuster, емм, так воно ж усе пов'язане. Я пропоную єдину систему вирішення. Саме «пунктуація» або, наприклад, «велика-чи-мала-літера» і створюють (-вали) перепони об'єднанню «орфографія»/«написання»/«правопис»/«orthography»/«spelling» в одну синонімічну групу (бо саме «пунктуація» не входить у поняття «орфографія», але входить у поняття «правопис»≈«orthography», і саме «велика-чи-мала-літера» не входить у поняття «spelling», але входить у поняття «орфографія»). Що не так?

Comment: Так, пов'язані, але не є частиною запитання. Те, що називається succinct. Тим більше, що наявна кількість запитань по кожній темі не дає можливості точно передбачити потрібну структуру теґів. Ну, наприклад, я прибив «проект-99», але залишив «латинку», і тепер не упевнений, що я зробив правильно. Тому я і намагаюся почати з найширших теґів спочатку, а потім робитимемо уточнення, виходячи з наявних запитань

Comment: @bytebuster, мабуть, у нас різний спосіб мислення.